# How to test in xunit that Event was raised?

Tags: c#, events, xunit

I defined simple event in class like that

```
class Request 
{
   protected virtual void OnStateChanged()
   {
      StateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public event EventHandler StateChanged;

   public void Approve()
   {
      OnStateChanged();
   }

}
```

how do I xunit that this event were raised ?

I tried one line event handler implementation

```
bool eventRaised = false;
request.StateChanged += (obj, eventArgs) => eventRaised = true;
request.Approve();
Assert.True(eventRaised);
```

it works, but is there any better approach ? I did not figure out, how to use `Assert.Raises()`

Comment: _is there any better approach_ - what push you for a better? What missing in current approach? We can suggest multiple different approaches by using different frameworks and start holy testing frameworks war ;)

Comment: It's totally okay, but it is 4 lines, I was thinking something like `Assert.Raises(request.StateChanged)` :D Also at first thought I thought I'd have to create a new method, now it's only 4 lines (but it could be one :-).

Comment: Wrap it with a method and use it as one line ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the commonly suggested approach

The following example however, shows how to use `Assert.Raises()` to test your provided class's event

```
var request = new Request();

var evt = Assert.Raises<EventArgs>(
    h => request.StateChanged += h,
    h => request.StateChanged -= h,
    () => request.Approve());

Assert.NotNull(evt);
Assert.Equal(request, evt.Sender);
Assert.Equal(EventArgs.Empty, evt.Arguments);
```

However, your event handler would need to be the generic delegate

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> StateChanged;
```

instead of just `EventHandler` in order for `Assert.Raises` to work as expected.

Comment: OK, but what if I cannot change the type of the event from the non-generic `EventHandler` because I'm implementing an interface? (e.g. `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`)?