# How to test for an event that is raised using an idle priority dispatcher?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, event-handling, xunit

I am in the process of familiarizing myself with xUnit and as an exercise I'm trying to achieve full coverage on my existing library code - among it a simple base class that implements `ICommand` using the common pattern where the `CanExecuteChanged`-event is routed through `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`:

```
    public abstract class BaseCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return CanExecute((T?)parameter);
        }

        public virtual bool CanExecute(T? parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            Execute((T?)parameter);
        }

        public abstract void Execute(T? parameter);

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }
```

So far, I had no problem creating unit tests for all methods except `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`. As far as I can tell there are at least two problems:

- xUnit's `Assert.Raises*()` methods only work with events that use the generic version of `EventHandler<>`, not the non-generic version required here (rf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919386 ). I came up with the following to work around this (`TestCommand` is simply declared as `class TestCommand : BaseCommand {}` so I could test the abstract class):

```
[Fact]
public void TestRaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    var sut = new TestCommand();
    bool changed = false;
    sut.CanExecuteChanged += (_, _) => changed => true;

    sut.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

    Assert.True(changed);
}
```

- As you can see above, the event is actually raised via `CommandManager` which internally invokes the event handler using a dispatcher with priority `Background` (rf. [`CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested()`](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandManager.cs,75821ace29985338,references) ). AFAICT, this means that I cannot handle the event synchronously in my test, i.e. the test shown above does not succeed because the event handler has not yet been called by the time that `Assert.True(changed)` is executed (it does succeed when I don't use the `CommandManager` pattern but rather raise the event directly).

So, what do I have to do in order to "wait" for the event to have fired?

Comment: Does `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds)` work? And just for the sake of completeness: this is an integration and not a unit test as you're relying on the real implementation of `CommandManager`

Comment: No, unfortunately, `await Task.Delay()` did not work (even after waiting 10 seconds). The event handler I assign just never gets called...
And good point about integration vs unit test in this case!